# Absolute table header for generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am generating tables with jquery/javascript while getting the from an ajax request. I do not know beforehand how wide the columns are going to be and how many columns I am going to have.

This takes me right to the problem: is it still possible to create an absolute table header with pure css, even though the widths of the columns are unknown?

I have tried a a few js solutions like [floatThead](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/), which work really well with small tables, but as soon as I am getting too many columns, the script is going to slow the browser down heavily, up to a point where the page is unusable.

Comment: if you don't have any events on the header, just clone the table header and fix it on an absolute or fixed position

Comment: if only it was that easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is the best solution, especially because without wide support for `position: sticky` the header will always be fixed in the viewport and cannot be contained inside the table element. You could also use the `clip` property to hide the header outside the table but support is also limited.

But if you insist upon CSS the only solution I can think of is to duplicate your entire table (which should be easy since it's already dynamically generated.) Fix the second table, move it up 100%, and hide everything but the table head.

```
table:nth-of-type(even) {
  position: fixed;
  transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}
table:nth-of-type(even) tbody:not(thead) * {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 800px;
}
td {
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table:not(:nth-of-type(even)) thead {
  visibility: hidden;
}
table:nth-of-type(even) {
  position: fixed;
  transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}
table:nth-of-type(even) thead tr {
  background: green;
}
table:nth-of-type(even) tbody:not(thead) * {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.clip-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, auto, auto, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="clip-wrapper">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>This is a test column to make it wider</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table><table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>This is a test column to make it wider</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Here's a second snippet that uses a container in order to have a `position: absolute` header instead of `position: fixed`. This method requires a scrollbox table but allows you to place it anywhere on a page since it's all contained. Supports IE 10+ because of `pointer-events: none`. If you have a set height on the header you can set the second tables height to that of the header, `overflow: hidden` and `display:block` on the second table for a more widely supported method. This is because the second table prevents you from scrolling by being in front of the scroll-wrapper.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.scroll-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.scroll-wrapper table thead {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.scroll-wrapper + table {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.scroll-wrapper + table thead tr {
  background: green;
}
.scroll-wrapper + table tbody:not(thead) * {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scroll-wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>This is a test column to make it wider</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>This is a test column to make it wider</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I would love to use a js solution but the performance suffers a lot from it, as the current table I am testing with got >100 columns. With plain css I do not have those problems.

Comment: @Marv Glad it's working for you. Since I don't know how you're placing this table in a page I added a snippet that puts the table in a scrollbox to address the always fixed on the page header.